# Schema Design Inquiry

Tags: database-design

In a timesheets data model, suppose I have an `employee` table, and a `job` table. Then, I also have an `employeeInJob` table to store an employee's rate for a given job e.g.

```
employeeInJob (
    employeeId,
    jobId,
    rate,
    effectiveFrom )
```

A given employee may have multiple entries in the `employeeInJob` table for a given job since his/her rate may vary for that position over time.

Now I have a timesheetEntry table:

```
timesheetEntry (
    employeeId,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    ???JobId )
```

My question is whether the `timesheetEntry` table should reference the `job` table or the `employeeInJob` table. I think having it point to the core `job` provides a more flexible design? Is this the case?

Comment: Do you have `JobId` column in `employeeInJob` table

Comment: Yes, sorry I used the word `role'.

Comment: `employeeId` in table `timesheetEntry` would be associated with `employee` table, I think you are sure of this :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better that `timesheetEntry` table should reference to `job` table as

`JobId` will be PK of `Job` table and so associating `timesheetEntry` with `job table` will provide better referential integrity of data